# Do I need any authorization to work and sign out performed maintenance on US-registered general aviation aircraft outside of USA?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-maintenance, faa-approval

I'm non-USA citizen and holder of FAA A&P Mechanic's certificate but haven't worked on US-registered aircraft since 1999 however all this time I'm involved in commercial aircraft maintenance and CAMO activities and currently have more than 6 months experience within the preceding 24 months on non-US registered aircraft under other country's CAA authorization. My questions are:

- Do I have to apply to FSDO to exercise privileges of my FAA certificate or is it considerable as current?
- To carry out maintenance on US-registered general aviation aircraft (Piper Aztec) outside of USA, do I have to have any special authorization from FAA?

Thank you in advance
Giorgi